# Why JEditorPane does not show image written in HTML?

Tags: java, html, swing, javafx, jeditorpane

So my HTML is this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body >
<h1 style="background-color:lightblue">This is a h1</h1>
<img src="haha.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142" > 
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how I load the HTML:

```
JEditorPane je = new JEditorPane();
je.setEditable(false);
je.setContentType("text/html");
FileReader fr = new FileReader("testPage.html");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String text = "";
String inputLine = br.readLine();
while(inputLine!=null){
    text += inputLine+"\n";
    inputLine=br.readLine();
}
je.setText(text);
SwingNode sn = new SwingNode();
sn.setContent(je);
```

The h1 part works perfectly, but the image part does not show up, which shows up in .html file. So I want to know if there is any way to make image in HTML show up? If `JEditorPane`  can't do it, what other component will show the html **WITH** images?

Help Appreciated.

Comment: Probably because it can't find the image, where is it stored in relationship to the code that's running it?

Comment: I used absolute file path. During run time, JEditorPane saves a space for the image, but the image is just broken....

Comment: Possible duplicate [How should HTML for Java components reference resources?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26795598/418556)

Comment: @AndrewThompson But there not embedded resources?

Comment: BTW - `<h1 style="background-color:lightblue">This is a h1</h1>`  Java (HTML rendering) does not understand `lightblue`.  Try instead `#DDDDFF`.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `SwingNode`, your application actually uses JavaFX.

JavaFX has a web browser component, you can read more about it here:

[Overview of the JavaFX `WebView` Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/overview.htm)

Here's a short example how to use it:

```
WebView browser = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
webEngine.load(url);
```

`url` can be an address like `"http://example.com"` or it can point to a file or resource like:

```
Paths.get("testPage.html").toURI().toURL();
```

If you have the HTML content as a `String`, you can load it like this:

```
String htmlContent = "<html>....</html>";
browser.getEngine().loadContent(htmlContent);
```

If you want to insert images in the `htmlContent`, you can do it like this:

```
URL url = Main.class.getResource("haha.jpg"); // haha.jpg is next to Main class
String text = "<html><img src=\"" + url + "\" width=\"104\" height=\"142\" > </html>";
```

Or if you want to insert an image pointing to a fixed file on your computer, create the `url` like this:

```
URL url = new File("C:/images/haha.jpg").toURI().toURL();
```

Or:

```
URL url = Paths.get("C:/images/haha.jpg").toUri().toURL();
```

Comment: Still not working. I used browser.getEngine().loadContent(text); The image was not successfully loaded.

Comment: ...I got it, after I used relative path in html file. !  But why it could not work when I used absolute path in html file, like <img src = "File:c/bla/bla/bla/haha.jpg" width="104" height="142" >

Comment: @Yvainovski Most likely because you left out a **colon**: `"file:/c:/bla/bla/bla/haha.jpg"` is the result of `new File("c:/bla/bla/bla/haha.jpg").toURI().toURL().toString()`.

Comment: Also, when i used(we is WebEngine) we.loadContent(text); It only showed the rim of the image . why?

Comment: @Yvainovski `WebEngine.loadContent()` expects an HTML string, not a URL! Use `WebEnigne.load(url)` if you have the address (url).

Comment: say String text = "<html> <img src=\"haha.jpg\" alt=\"W3Schools.com\" width=\"104\" height=\"142\" > </html>"  we.loadContent(text), then it only shows the rim of image.....

Comment: @Yvainovski Because the browser component don't know the source of the relative `"haha.jpg"` image. Use this if `"haha.jpg"` is in the same package as your class, it works both from a file and also if packaged as a jar: `URL url = YourClass.class.getResource("haha.jpg"); String text = "<html><img src=\""+url+"\" width=\"104\" height=\"142\" > </html>";`

Answer (score 1):

I copied an image into the same working directory from where the program was executed and using the following HTML...

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body >
        <h1 style="background-color:lightblue">This is a h1</h1>
        <img src="haha.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142" > 
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

And code...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestEditor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestEditor();
    }

    public TestEditor() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
                try {
                    editor.setPage(new File("testPage.html").toURI().toURL());
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(editor));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Was able to get it to run without problems...

[image: Editor]

Put the image in the relative location from the program execution context (".")

Comment: I'm using JavaFX. when i instead use editor.setPage(new File("testPage.html").toURI().toURL()); It shows a mass.

Comment: Then why are you using a `JEditorPane`?

Comment: If you are using `JavaFX` then why don't you use `WebView`?

Comment: @Yvainovski Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses