# java swing get attribute style of div html

Tags: java, html, swing

I want to get url img "assets/img/slider1.jpg".
file index.hrml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="carousel-content" style="background-image:url(assets/img/slider1.jpg)"></div>                                           
    </body>
</html>
```

I use the code below it to null.
Result Img: null.

Please help me.

```
public class getStyleHTML {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost/test/test/index.html");
            HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit(); 
            HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) kit.createDefaultDocument(); 
            Reader HTMLReader = new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            kit.read(HTMLReader, doc, 0);
            ElementIterator it = new ElementIterator(doc);
            Element elem = null;
            while ( (elem = it.next()) != null ){ 
                if( elem.getName().equals("div")){ 
                   String div = (String) elem.getAttributes().getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.STYLE);
                   System.out.println("Img: "+div);
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: sorry code index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Home</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="carousel-content" style="background-image:url(assets/img/slider1.jpg)"></div>           
 </body>
</html>

Comment: You might want to [edit] that into your post, so it can be formatted as code to make it more readable.

Comment: See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26795598/418556) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `css` command to get `background-image`. Then, you can get rid of `url` syntax as shown below:

```
var string =$("div").css("background-image");
string = string.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
```

The `string` contains the url content. Look at the working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zero_point/4x8ntd75/). You need to use jQuery by the way.